# Including custom buttons in Eclipse package

Tags: custom-button, eclipse

I have created some custom buttons on the Task object, and am creating a package in Eclipse to migrate.  For some reason, I don't see an option to include such  buttons when I select the metadata components.  I thought I had done this before, but don't seem to be able to do so now.  Maybe I'm just looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the buttons are under a section called "weblinks" as opposed to "buttons".

Answer (score 0):

Button details are included in the record's meta data. So if you have Task object's meta data in the project, do a

> Force.com -> Refresh from server

for the Task object, and you should see the button's details included in the meta data.